# Ruby extend DateTime only in class

Tags: json, ruby, datetime, serialization

I want to change the way a `DateTime` is serialized in `Hash#to_json` for a higher precision.

```
require 'date'
require 'json'
puts ({my_time: DateTime.now}.to_json) # => {"my_time":"2018-01-17T15:34:30+00:00"}
```

This working example includes milliseconds:

```
require 'date'
require 'json'
class A
  class ::DateTime
    def as_json(*)
      iso8601(3)
    end

    def to_json(*args)
      as_json.to_json(*args)
    end
  end

  def serialize_hash
    {my_time: DateTime.now}.to_json
  end
end
```

This overrides `DateTime#to_json` to produce the expected result, but the change is global. I need to change `DateTime.to_json` in **only** class `A`.

```
# Includes milliseconds, as expected
puts A.new.serialize_hash # => {"my_time":"2018-01-17T15:33:44.348+00:00"}

# Outside class A
# Should not include milliseconds
puts ({my_other_time: DateTime.now}.to_json) # => {"my_other_time":"2018-01-17T15:33:44.348+00:00"}
```

This global change is making one of my gems fail to load with `TypeError: superclass mismatch for class DateTime`.

This is a pure Ruby implementation. No Rails.

**Edit**: per @SergioTulentsev's recommendation I am now working with refinements.

```
require 'date'
require 'json'
module DateTimeExtensions
  refine DateTime do
    def as_json(*)
      iso8601(3)
    end

    def to_json(*args)
      as_json.to_json(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

It looks like `Hash#to_json` cannot see my refinement.

```
using DateTimeExtensions
# Has milliseconds, as expected
puts DateTime.now.to_json # => "2018-01-17T16:23:46.043+00:00"
# Should also have milliseconds, but does not
puts ({my_time: DateTime.now}.to_json) # => {"my_time":"2018-01-17T16:23:46+00:00"}
```

Comment: That's exactly what refinements do. Read up on this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev or this is exactly what explicit call to `iso8601` would do:  `{my_time: DateTime.now.iso8601(3)}.to_json` :)

Comment: Read this post about how Refinements work http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/12/13/ruby-refinements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This manually serializes all `DateTime` values in the hash (and nested hashes) to the specified format. After this `my_hash.to_json` will show the correct precision.

```
require 'date'
require 'json'

module HashExtensions
  refine Hash do
    def deep_traverse(&block)
      stack = self.map{ |k,v| [ [k], v ] }
      while not stack.empty?
        key, value = stack.pop
        yield(key, value)
        if value.is_a? Hash
          value.each{ |k,v| stack.push [ key.dup << k, v ] }
        end
      end
    end

    def deep_update(&block)
      deep_traverse do |keys, v|
        if keys.length == 1
          self[keys.first] = block.call(v)
        else
          self.dig(*keys.first(keys.length - 1))&.[]=(keys.last, block.call(v))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Test for nested hashes:

```
h = {
  d1: DateTime.now,
  level1: {
    d2: DateTime.now,
    level2: {
      d3: DateTime.now,
    }
  }
}
using HashExtensions
h.deep_update do |v|
  if v.is_a? DateTime
     v.iso8601(3)
  else
    v
  end
end
puts h
```